# C++ Initializer_List into Vector of Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, std

I've been trying to streamline some of my code, condensing and making calls easier where I can. One of the things I've been trying to do is fuse two common overloads I have all over the place into one. They are as follows:

```
void MyClass::addSomething(Something & a)
{
   vectorOfSomething.push_back(&a)
}

void MyClass::addSomething(std::vector<Something*> a)
{
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
      vectorOfSomething.push_back(a[i]);
}
```

The class Something is abstract. vectorOfSomething is a vector of pointers to Somethings.

Essentially, instead of having to do this:

```
std::Vector mySomethings = {&something1, &something2};
addSomething(mySomethings);
```

I want to do this:

```
addSomething({something1, something2});
```

So it is more similar to the first overload (no need for the user to create a vector of pointers first). Looking around the two ways I saw were either through: std::initializer_list or variadic templates, both of which I am not afraid to admit is completely foreign to me.

I've given it a shot with initializer lists but have run into a ton of errors trying various things. I've managed to get the function to actually accept the list, but I can't quite figure out how to get it to populate the vector correctly. The main issue seems to be that the init list has values that are 'const' within.

If anyone has any idea on how to make this work I would be grateful!

Comment: Why vector of pointers? If you want to share the ownership of the objects, between the vector and the original object scope, consider using std::shared_ptr. The only reasons to have a vector of pointers (Which should be smart pointers, never naked pointers) are ownership sharing (explained above) and polymorphism. I don't see neither of them in your code. I pay for ownership sharing, but you explicit pointer usage it's annoying for me.

Comment: So please show us more context about what are you training to solve.

Comment: In c++11, you can use the syntax `addSomething({something1, something2});` with the function that you already have: [ideone](http://ideone.com/wW1Te7).

Comment: @Manu343726 The reason for the vector of pointers is polymorphism. What I am implementing is a list of graphics of various types that are all drawn in a for loop. The abstract base contains the drawing function. I will admit I had not looked at smart pointers for this issue thus far, maybe it is something I will do if my explicits are bad practice!

Comment: @user2079303 Well look at that, it does! That makes the vector usage a bit less annoying, but I still am hoping for a solution that will take addSomething({something1, something2}) without the objects being pointers yet.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

struct MyClass {
    template <typename It >
    void Add( It b, It e ) {
        data_.insert( end(data_), b, e );
    }

    void Add( std::initializer_list<int> const & elems ) { 
        Add( begin(elems), end(elems) ); 
    }

    template <typename T>
    void Add( T const & cont ) {
        Add( begin(cont), end(cont) ); 
    }

    std::vector<int> data_;

    friend std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & os, MyClass const & mc ) {
        for( auto & e : mc.data_ )
            os << e << " ";
        return os;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass foo;

    foo.Add( { 1, 3 });

    std::vector<int> v { 1,2};
    foo.Add( v );

    std::list<int> l { 4,5};
    foo.Add( l );

    std::cout << foo;
}
```

A compiler cannot infer a template argument to initializer_list, the specialization has to be explicit.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! When I try this method I'm still getting the error: cannot convert 'const Something' to 'Something*'. I can't say I'm too familiar with how these template types work, but I've tried changing around what is being passed and all I can seem to do is cause more errors. Any ideas?